# What happened to "Make async ValueTask/ValueTask methods ammortized allocation-free"?

Tags: .net, memory-management, async-await

Steven Toub introduced ~allocation-free `ValueTask<T>`s to .NET 5. From his deeply educational saga [Performance Improvements in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-5/):

```
Method           Runtime        Mean       Ratio    Allocated
ValueTaskCost   .NET FW 4.8     1,635.6 us  1.00    294010 B
ValueTaskCost   .NET Core 3.1   842.7 us    0.51    120184 B
ValueTaskCost   .NET 5.0        812.3 us    0.50    186 B     <--- !
```

I first came across this in a post by the Dapper hero Marc Gravell [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html), where he recommends mostly always using `ValueTask` instead of `Task` (though interestingly Dapper does not do this).

The feature could be enabled with an environment variable `DOTNET_SYSTEM_THREADING_POOLASYNCVALUETASKS`, which does not appear to exist any longer in .NET today.

What happened? Was there a technical reason this was removed, or perhaps made default?

Comment: Dapper doesn't do this because a: because IIRC the Dapper API predates ValueTask and b: we will usually be going out-of-process and often off-box, so: true async - it wouldn't be a meaningful optimization

Comment: (plus ADO.NET is itself inherently quite allocatey)

Comment: ’allocatey’ is my new favorite villain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experimental feature was replaced [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/50116) with a custom builder implementation, which is used on a method-by-method basis by adding the attribute:

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder<>))]
```

(or the non-generic equlivalent)

Comment: A search for this attribute yielded this informative writing on the matter: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/